# Proving commutativity of unknown operator in a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The group $(G,\ast)$ is defined on the set $\{e,a,b,c\}$ where $e$ denotes the identity element. Prove that $a\ast b=b\ast a$.

Note: $\ast$ is not to be mistaken as the multiplication operator.

Any hints on how to approach this?

Comment: $ab$ has to be one of $\{e, a, b, c\}$. Which could it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** There are only two groups of order 4 up to isomorphism. If you can show both are commutative, you're done. To get you started: Consider the elements of $G$, and in particular their orders. The identity $e$ will always have order $1$. If any element has order $4$, then what can you say? If no element has order $4$, use [Lagrange's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)) to see what their orders must be, and try to write down a multiplication table for $G$ under this assumption. There is only one way to do this (up to isomorphism).

Comment: if any element has order 4, then G would be cyclic and all cyclic groups are abelian hence the operator is commutative. By Lagrange's theorem, the order of any element can only be 1,2 or 4. Can't be 1, as only the identity has order one, hence must be order 2. Wow that all fits perfectly....thanks!